# transfer of litecoin from mobile wallet to metamask

Tags: wallets

I have litecoin in an mobile wallet (bx.in.th) and would like to know how to send this to my metamask wallet.  Not finding answers.

Thanks.

Comment: You need to use an exchange to convert your litecoin into ether. You cannot send litecoin directly to an ethereum wallet.

Answer (score 2):

Metamask is for ether and erc20 tokens only. Litecoin goes in a different wallet.